# Matlab: writing multiple tables with cell2table

Tags: excel, matlab

I would like to write multiple tables in a matlab for loop. As an input i use a excel file that contains multiple sheets. Yhe amount of sheets and the size of the data is not prefixed. The reading of this files goes right but once i save it to a table it overwrites the same table over and over again.

The clue would be a flexible name in the cell2table function. I have these names in sheetname (all) and Sheet (current). Does anyone has a suggestion?

```
[type,sheetname] = xlsfinfo('\Matlab\dienstregeling.xlsx'); 
m=size(sheetname,2);
for(i=1:m); 
Sheet = char(sheetname(1,i)); 
[num, text, raw] = xlsread('\Matlab\dienstregeling.xlsx',Sheet);

test = cell2table(raw);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a structure and [generate the field names](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) from the variable `Sheet`:

```
test = struct;
for(i=1:m); 
   Sheet = char(sheetname(1,i)); 
   [num, text, raw] = xlsread('\Matlab\dienstregeling.xlsx',Sheet);
   test.(Sheet) = cell2table(raw);
end
```

Comment: That is the solution. I was already trying for an entire day. Thanks.